# Flash video player that supports streaming m4v files

Tags: javascript, video, video-streaming, m4v

I'm looking for a Flash video player that is able to stream m4v files on all browsers. Example file:
http://podcasts.cnn.net/cnn/big/podcasts/cnnnewsroom/video/2010/11/23/the.daily.11.23.cnn.m4v

Unfortunately, I can't convert the format since it originates from 3rd party servers. I can't rely on HTML5 video since not all browsers support this format and the encoding it contains.

I've already tried several players such as JW Player, Kaltura, Video JS, Projekktor, and more. Testing them with Firefox and IE, some of them couldn't play the m4v file at all, while others downloaded the entire file before starting to play it.

If an open source solution is available, and one that has a powerful JavaScript API, that would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: Note that "streaming" is the wrong word here..

Comment: What I mean by streaming, is playing the file on the fly as it downloads, rather than playing it only after it has finished downloading. If you can suggest a better term I'll edit my question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [VLC](http://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation%3aWebPlugin) or write your [own code](http://mirificampress.com/permalink/m4v_video_player).

Comment: Won't using VLC work only if the user has installed the VLC player?

Comment: Definitely yes. Like a flash plugin/ActiveX. Anyway you may use self-written player from the example.

Answer (score 1):

What I found was the html5 videos,jplayer plugin and video js.And all i was able to explore.as mozilla is never able to play m4v file it always needs a .ogv as fallback file.it needs to be specific codecs installed in every machines.

If you're not forced to use Quicktime, the Flash based [Long Tail Video Player](http://www.longtailvideo.com/) is free and can do Quicktime encoded MV4 if the client has Flash 10 installed.

Hence tried using the **JWPlayer** from the official site of **jwplayer**. 
Will have to purchase it to get a licence key.Now able to play **.m4v** video on cross browsers.It works perfectly.